# Why do people like use erc721 to public NFT instead of erc1155?

Tags: solidity, nft

In theory, the ERC1155 can fulfill everything the ERC721 can, and more gas-efficient.
So Why do people like use erc721 to public NFT instead of erc1155?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one main thing that ERC-721 does that ERC-1155 doesn’t — you can ask a ERC-721 contract who the `ownerOf(itemId)` is, whereas on an ERC-1155 contract you can only check whether a specific account is the owner (by checking `balanceOf(account, itemId)`).

Having said that, most of the time the decision to use ERC-721 over ERC-1155 is because of ERC-721 enjoying (until now) better support across explorers, wallets, marketplaces, etc.

Comment: Very enlightening answer！